# Write an expression in terms of $x$

Tags: probability

There are $10$ pens in a bag, $x$ of these pens are red and the rest are blue. Write an expression in terms of $x$ for the probability of taking two and getting one of each colour out of the bag. I had this in my gcse maths exam today i found the answer to be $\frac{x}{10}$ times by $\frac{b}{10}$ could someone tell me if this is correct thanks.

Comment: In what way are the pens taken out of the bag?

Comment: it didn't specify i assume just both taken at the same time

Comment: You have to specify "with" or "without" replacement.  Without replacement, the answer is $2\times \frac x{10} \times \frac {10-x}9$.  With replacement it is $2\times \frac x{10} \times \frac {10-x}{10}$.  In both cases, the factor of $2$ comes from the fact that you can draw the colors in either order.

Comment: do you not mention b anywhere

Comment: if b is the number of blue pens in the bag, then b = 10-x

Answer (score 1):

When you say you take two marbles, I'm assuming you pick $2$ distinct marbles out of the bag at once. The total number of outcomes is $\dbinom{10}{2} = 45.$ If we want to get one of each color, then there are $x(10 - x)$ successful outcomes. The answer is $\boxed{\frac{x(x - 10)}{45}}.$